# Chatter not uploading a file

Tags: visualforce, chatter

We had an odd one crop up. We have a VisualForce page we use for case management. When a case is a master case, we can add upload files to the Chatter feed. When the case is not a master case, you cannot attach a file to the chatter feed. Everything looks good until you click on the "Share" button then the chatter component and button gray out but nothing happens.

Any ideas?

In either page, the chatter component is added with the tag:

```
<chatter:feedWithFollowers entityId="{!c.Id}" />
```

There isn't any other script around it so I'm at a loss.

Comment: OK so using FireFox's debugging tools, it looks like it comes down to this in the script for the Chatter feed. ActionProgressDialog.prototype.createContent=function(){var b=document.getElementById(this.getContentId()) The issue is that document.getElementById( this.getContentId() ) is returning null. Later in the script where it tries to set d.innerHTML to a value, the script fails.

Answer (score 2):

We found out that this was due to some other script that was introduced then part of it removed. As a side effect, the script built into the chatter handling was also broken.